# Need advice: SQL database design

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc

I'm getting ready to start the design of a database for a ASP.NET MVC application and I had a quick question about the best way to store information in a table.

In the old version of my database, I had a table called `Phones` and It had around 40-50 different columns.

Rather than having so many columns in a table, would you recommend keeping the "essential" data in the `Phones` table and then creating an additional table called `PhoneDetails` with the rest of the data?

Thanks for your input!

### Update

Here are the columns that are in my table: (there are 59 total)

```
       [PhoneID]
      ,[Make]
      ,[Model]
      ,[ProcessorSpeed]
      ,[Dimensions]
      ,[Weight]
      ,[RAM]
      ,[Storage]
      ,[BatterySize]
      ,[TalkTime]
      ,[StandbyTime]
      ,[DisplayType]
      ,[Resolution]
      ,[DisplaySize]
      ,[RearCamera]
      ,[FrontCamera]
      ,[MinOS]
      ,[MaxOS]
      ,[NFC]
      ,[Notes]
      ,[Publish]
      ,[FullName]
      ,[Date]
      ,[Colors]
      ,[Sensors]
      ,[SIMCardType]
      ,[ChargingConnectors]
      ,[AVConnectors]
      ,[SystemConnectors]
      ,[USBVersion]
      ,[BluetoothVersion]
      ,[BluetoothProfiles]
      ,[WiFiVersion]
      ,[WiFiSecurityModes]
      ,[WirelessConnectivity]
      ,[GSMTypes]
      ,[GSMUpload]
      ,[GSMDownload]
      ,[LTETypes]
      ,[LTEUpload]
      ,[LTEDownload]
      ,[WCDMATypes]
      ,[WCDMAUpload]
      ,[WCDMADownload]
      ,[BatteryVoltage]
      ,[RemoveableBattery]
      ,[MaxMusicPlayback]
      ,[MaxVideoPlayback]
      ,[MaxWiFiTime]
      ,[ProcessorName]
      ,[ProcessorType]
      ,[RearAperture]
      ,[RearFocalLength]
      ,[RearMinFocusRange]
      ,[FlashType]
      ,[FlashOperatingRange]
      ,[FrontResolution]
      ,[FrontAperture]
      ,[DeviceGeneration]
```

Comment: What were the columns of the Phones table?

Answer (score 1):

40-50 columns sounds like allot of columns, more than I can imagine required for a "phones" tables, but without further information about what those columns are, It is really hard to give carved in stone truths.

In general if your table looks something like this:

```
Id Motorola Nokia LG HTC ...many more...
----------------------------------------
1     1      0    0   0     .....
2     0      0    0   1     .....
3     0      1    0   0     .....
4     1      0    0   0     .....
5     0      0    1   0     .....
```

you definitely should normalize your DB to something more like:

Phones:

```
Id   PhoneTypeId
---------------
1     1    
2     4    
3     2    
4     1    
5     3
```

PhoneType:

```
Id   TypeName
---------------
1     Motorola    
2     Nokia    
3     LG    
4     HTC
```

Of course, this is just an example, but this is the best I can offer without further information regarding the nature of the columns is `Phones` table.

Answer (score 0):

You should think about normalizing your one table if needed and if the table really has relationships, otherwise there is not much to be gained by just splitting a table into two separate tables. Think about are there redundant data in any of the columns?

In that case you can have a separate table with that info and a FK relationship between them.

Answer (score 0):

Its good to create another table for save the phone details with FK reference, because there have so many fields.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider splitting into 2 tables. If it meets any of the below 2 conditions.

If there are large number of rows in some columns with NULL values.

or

If your application is accessing essential columns  more often than the remaining columns.